# WPF - Margin space is always black

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, margin

When i set the margin, its space is always black. How can i change that? I'm using VS2012, .net 4.5.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid Background="Aqua" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>Nome</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="100"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the background of the `Border`.